# C# Call Jupyter Notebook

Tags: c#, azure, jupyter-notebook

From a .Net C# front end, I need to call and pass parameters to a Jupyter notebook.   The Jupyter notebook then returns a string.   I am developing under Windows 10 Professional and will need to run on an Azure Windows Server VM.   My searches have found info about Jupyter calling C#. Again, my requirement is the reverse.   Help is appreciated.

Comment: Another option:  My C# programs succesfully calls Python using Processstartinfo call.   Can this call sequence work:  C# calls Python with then call Jupyter Notebook.   Jupyter returns string to Python and passed back to C#.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The nbconvert API function allows Python to call a Jupyter notebook.

https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-using-the-python-api-interface.   I'll test this flow and report back:  C # -> Python - > Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it differently since there is no straightforward legit approach like a library/api method call. Even if there exists any hacky way, I am not aware of.

Run the notebook as a REST API locally using something like [Jupyter Kernel Gateway](https://github.com/jupyter/kernel_gateway/blob/master/README.md). A simple [blog post](https://ndres.me/post/jupyter-notebook-rest-api/) has an example. Call the REST API from C# just like a regular http client.