# Start a jupyter notebook from Unity3D

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to build a Unity application that I want to use to enter parameters which I want to pass to a jupyter notebook. The notebook should then be executed which results in a CSV file, which again needs to be saved locally or passed to the Unity environment.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I know off

### A) Run Jupyter Notebook as an API then use C# rest requests to call the functions

Haven't done this myself but probably the cleanest approach.

[C# Call Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040848/c-sharp-call-jupyter-notebook)

### B) Jupyter Notebook can be called via commandline

[Passing command line arguments to argv in jupyter/ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook)

You can also make command line/Batch calls from C#. Combining the two will allow you do do it

[Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)